# Problem with grid layout. Blocks falls out from their inherit block

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have one problem with one of my pages.
A few blocks falls out from their inherit block, and I can't find a problem with it.

If you help me i will much appreciate it.

Here is the link on page - https://nickolasdzr.github.io/grid-layout/
and after go into the page just resize it on 320px, and see on 'portfolio-section.

Comment: You need to describe the specific problem and what you did to try to fix it.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that the `.portfolio-section` tries to use all available space including the padding if it gets smaller. What you want you to do is, at the respective adjust your css like so:

```css
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .portfolio-section {
    grid-template-columns: minmax(100%, 1fr);
  }
}
```

This assures that it will take `1fr` at max but only `100%` of its available space in width and prevent horizontal overflow.

If you want to read further on this, there is an Article on [Smashing Magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/09/css-grid-gotchas-stumbling-blocks/#can-grid-track-sizing-be-dictated-by-content) where it is explained in more detail.